# DataBindingComponent class file not found with Gradle Plugin version 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I am getting below error after updating gradle plugin `version to 3.5.2`.

> com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent not found.

Everything works fine with gradle plugin `version 3.3.2`.

More info about libraries I am using:
`dagger = 2.25.2`
`android annotations = 4.6.0`

Please help if anyone has came across this issue.

Comment: have you make databinding true in gradle

Comment: Yes, databinding enabled flag is set to true.